# Python 2.7.5 getting import OrderedDict ImportError: No module named OrderedDict

Tags: python-2.7, ordereddictionary

import OrderedDict
ImportError: No module named OrderedDict

i'm using python 2.7.5 and assume orderedDict module to be pre-installed.
How can i check if the module is present and if not how can i install it.

I'm beginner and thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) belongs to the `collections` module. It is not standalone.

You need to `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Comment: from collectoins import OrderedDict
ImportError: No module named collectoins
I get the same error

Comment: sorry , i did the correction on "from collections import OrderedDict" and didnt face the import error. But " data1= json.loads(data,object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
NameError: name 'collections' is not defined" . How can i solve name error ? sorry if i was too amateur.

Comment: @RaviKumar When you do `from collections import OrderedDict`, you are modifying the namespace such that in order to access `OrderedDict`, you need not specify the module it belongs to. You are trying to access via `collections.OrderedDict`, either change that to just `OrderedDict` or change your import to `import collections`.

Comment: thanks a lot , am getting to understand the concept now.

Comment: You don't use comments to ask questions of that size on here. Open up a new question. Also, it seems to me that you're copying code from somewhere and just trying to get it to run without making an effort to learn. We generally don't respect that around here.

Comment: sorry for that @joshuarli  i will make an effort to solve it . thanks for your feedback . cheers

Answer (score 0):

Expanding what JoshuaRLi said, you want

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
```

You can check which modules you have available with

```
>>> help('modules')
```

Answer (score 0):

This question came up when I was trying to find a solution to a similar issue, so I post this here for anyone else that has this problem.

I received this error when trying to import `gstools`:

```
import gstools as gs
```

Notice that part of the error says:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    from typing_extensions import OrderedDict
else:
    from collections import OrderedDict
```

So updating to python 3.9 or greater imported from `collections` instead of `typing_extensions`, fixing my problem.